# What is a good way to trace filesystem changes?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

In application troubleshooting or debugging scenarios, on occasion I've encountered a desire to get a stream or log showing me all of the filesystem changes that a program may be performing. Sometimes applications have some pretty complex behaviors and race-conditions based on contents of configuration files that may be being changed, and things of that nature. The emphasis here would be on having a way to monitor at a low granularity the evolution of files on disk.

In particular I'm looking for dumping out a stream of file diffs. So my first instinct was to look at file watcher tools, maybe something like fswatch, the concept would be to use whatever relevant OS feature (FSEvents/kqueue/inotify) to hook a directory, make a temporary full copy of the directory, and then use it against that for diffing when we get events.

This might work well for many things, but before I dived into implementing that, it occured to me that this is probably fundamentally vulnerable to race conditions in which any application could write to a file multiple times quickly and there is no way for my FS watching system to force the filesystem to block until it's able to generate the diff before continuing. So this would be unable to guarantee a log of **all** changes, though it would be potentially the only practical way to go about it if the processes modifying the files in question are unknown or uncontrollable. How do I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not such a huge problem, because usually there is enough context in the situation to work out what's going on with out the heavy duty tools. But if not...

Once the processes involved in modifying the files become known (which again typically is a non issue to work out, though on Linux there is `auditd`) we can just `strace` the process.

I guess the problem would then come down to maybe wanting some way to pause that process once we see that it has modified a file *in case it might immediately modify that file again* in order to ensure we can obtain a diff of what it just changed.

At this point I'm starting to question the value of a tool that does something this specific... I think there is a use case where you have a mess of multiple processes modifying files in an unpredictable way and it is valuable simply to have a trace of what happened and in what sequence. But the concept of trying to stop processes right after it writes doesn't seem sound because it will likely change the resulting behavior (chaos theory and all that).

I'm sure strace on the relevant processes would get us 90% of the way there but the last 10% remains a bit unclear for me, if we can configure strace to trace the arguments it should be sufficient, and doing it as fast as possible should improve the chances of not interfering with results. I think various tracing tooling that is available with Linux can come to the rescue here (as well as deal with the fact that stracing processes by itself will slow them down a lot already).